# useDispatch doesn't dispatch to the reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to convert an existing project to `configureStore` from `createStore`.

store.js :

```js
export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    articlesList: loadArticlesReducer
  }
});
```

home.js :

```js
const articlesList = useSelector((state) => state.articlesList);
const dispatch = useDispatch()

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getArticles());
})
```

articleSlice.js :

```js
const articleSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'articles',
  initialState : [],
  reducers : {
    loadArticlesReducer: (state, action) => {
      console.log("WE NEVER REACH THIS CODE") <=== the problem is here
      state = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

export const { loadArticlesReducer } = articleSlice.actions;

export const getArticles = () => dispatch => {
  fetch("https://....")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      dispatch(loadArticlesReducer(data))
    })
};
```

The problem, as stated in the comment, is that `getArticles` action never dispatches the data to `loadArticlesReducer`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you get any errors or warnings in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loadArticlesReducer` is an action creator, not a reducer function. I suggest renaming the action creator so its purpose isn't confusing to future readers (*including yourself*) and actually exporting the reducer function.

Example:

```
const articleSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'articles',
  initialState : [],
  reducers : {
    loadArticlesSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

export const { loadArticlesSuccess } = articleSlice.actions;

export const getArticles = () => dispatch => {
  fetch("https://....")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      dispatch(loadArticlesSuccess(data));
    });
};

export default articleSlice.reducer; // <-- export reducer function
```

```
import articlesReducer from '../path/to/articles.slice';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    articlesList: articlesReducer
  }
});
```

You may also want to consider converting `getArticles` to a more idiomatic RTK thunk function using [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk). You'd use the slice's `extraReducers` to handle the fulfilled Promise returned from the Thunk. Example:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const getArticles = createAsyncThunk(
  "articles/getArticles",
  () => {
    return fetch("https://....")
      .then(response => response.json());
  }
);

const articleSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'articles',
  initialState : [],
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addCase(getArticles.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state = action.payload;
    });
  },
});

export default articleSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: @ChristosLoupassakis It just occurred to me that you should probably also be writing more current Thunk functions. I've added an update to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start), you'll need to replace the following line:

```js
export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    articlesList: loadArticlesReducer // <= This currently points to the exported actions and not the reducer
  }
});
```

With this one:

```js
import articleReducer from './articleSlice.js'

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    articlesList: articleReducer
  }
});
```

You'll need to export the reducer from the `articleSlice.js` of course:

```js
export default articleSlice.reducer;
```

---

As a general tip, always reproduce the examples from the documentation using exactly the same setup and naming, and once it works, customize the code accordingly in a slow step by step manner. It's easy to miss something while replicating such complicated setups if there's no 1-to-1 correspendence with the original code.